# Ruby on Rails HABTM adding records to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to use a Has and belongs to many relationship to link users to teams, the issue I am having is that I cannot work out how to add the ids into my user_teams table.

In my model I have done the following

User Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
```

Team Model

```
has_many :users
```

Teams Controller

```
def create
    @team = Team.new(params[:team])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @team.save
        @team.users << User.find(current_user)
        format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Team was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @team, status: :created, location: @team }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have proper relationship. You should to take care of association and habtm migration, Have a look to below example, I have two model "User" and "Organization"

organization model

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users,
      :association_foreign_key => 'user_id',
      :class_name => 'User',
      :join_table => 'organizations_users'
  attr_accessible :address, :name
end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations,
    :association_foreign_key => 'organization_id',
    :class_name => 'Organization',
    :join_table => 'organizations_users'
  attr_accessible :name, :phone
end
```

Then need to create new OrganizationsUsers migration like below.

```
class CreateOrganizationsUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :organizations_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :organization
      t.references :user
    end
    add_index :organizations_users, [:organization_id, :user_id]
    add_index :organizations_users, [:user_id, :organization_id]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :organizations_users
  end
end
```

You can get working example from [here](https://github.com/diatmpravin/habtm-demo.git).

Comment: fantastic response, it has cleared it up heaps on how to setup the migration and the relationship